# Are there any karma based wiki systems?

Tags: wiki

Are you aware of any wiki like system that make page edits public only if the user who made the edit has a given karma or if the community up votes the edit?

Something like Super User or Stack Overflow, with the difference that what gets graded is the article edit (and the user responsible for the edition) instead of a question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the Giant Bomb (Whiskey Media) engine does this.

Wiki edit task queue (with bounty)

http://www.giantbomb.com/wikid/task/queue/

Random user page

http://www.giantbomb.com/profile/johnthegamer/

etc, etc. click around to dig deeper.

Whiskey Media is the company that created the engine -- it also powers http://animevice.com